# Casting a char array to an integer

Tags: c++

Basically I am reading a binary format where 4 bytes specify the size of the string to follow. So i want to cast 4 chars I am reading from a buffer to 1 integer.

Here is what I have.

```
int FileReader::getObjectSizeForMarker(int cursor, int eof, char * buffer) {
  //skip the marker and read next 4 byes
  int cursor = cursor + 4; //skip marker and read 4
  char tmpbuffer[4] = {buffer[cursor], buffer[cursor+1], buffer[cursor+2], buffer[cursor+3]};
  int32_t objSize = tmpbuffer;
  return objSize;

}
```

thoughts?

Comment: Actually, you should probably say "bytes" rather than "characters".

Comment: And you need to know whether the data is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: data is large-endian i believe.

Comment: And, if the endianness works out, I'd be tempted to just alias an `int*` over the `char*`.

Comment: 00 00 00 40, so i think thats large endian

Comment: @j_mcnally Is it coming from a network stream? Those are indeed big-endian.

Comment: Yes, that's big endian. Most machines these days are little-endian, so you'd need to do the conversion manually (or with `ntohl`)

Comment: Then you will need to do a byte-swap if your machine is little-endian.

Comment: Or just do the shifts manually...though that's definitely a little nastier.

Comment: great info here guys thanks alot.

Comment: Why do you copy it into a new buffer? What's wrong with the buffer it was already in?

Comment: i have no idea david, it seemed like i'd need to, in order to cast it.

Comment: i see how the ptr solutions don't need the cast or the buffer copy, so i will be using it instead. thanks @DavidSchwartz!

Comment: You're right, you would need to do it to cast it to make it aligned. But as I think you now see, casting it is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty easy to do the unpacking manually:

```
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)(buffer + cursor);
// unpack big-endian order
int32_t objSize = (ptr[0] << 24) | (ptr[1] << 16) | (ptr[2] << 8) | ptr[3];
```

Comment: much easier to type than mine, but only because I wasn't sure if the implicit upcasts to int extended the sign out of each byte. shows how rusty my bit shifts are.

Comment: this looks good. I don't know which one to pick, this seems to take the big endian into account more than casting and bit switching which relieves me of the problem of having to detect what the platform expects. Am I correct?

Comment: is this significant? fileReader.cpp: In member function 'int FileReader::getObjectSizeForMarker(int, int, char*)':
fileReader.cpp:59: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'unsigned char*'

Comment: @j_mcnally: I think both WhozCraig's solution and my solution are fine w.r.t. endianness, though mine requires a bit less casting :)

Comment: this seems to work great 00 00 00 40, returns 64 which is correct. is int still the correct return type even tho im returning a int32_t, which i assume is a template from what i remember, that probably wraps an int in some way.

Comment: `int32_t` is the most pedantically correct type. Note that `int` is only guaranteed to have a 16-bit range in C (even if it is 32-bit on most platforms), so you should return `int32_t` if you want to be correct in that regard.

Comment: This answer (the cast to int32_t*) violates strict aliasing, resulting in UB. On some platforms this code can result in an illegal memory access due to an incorrectly aligned pointer. On other platforms where this appears to work it can perform poorly.

Comment: o really? so is Craigs the real solution @bames53?

Comment: The first suggestion was only a suggestion (my recommended approach was the second). So I'll just remove the first part, thanks.

Comment: o, ok so the 2nd one is cool, the 2nd one was the issue. o ok! win!

Comment: @j_mcnally yeah, if the value is serialized in a platform independent manner. std::memcpy would work if the stored data is endian dependent.

Comment: im new to the stuff but learning a ton, thanks guys! can you explain the (unsigned char *)(buffer + cursor) what does buffer + cursor do? since buffer is my entire file, i don't get what adding cursor which is an int of the location my read starts from, i dont get what this does. I'm sure it has to do with memory addresses but i guess i don't get it.

Comment: Buffer + cursor is basically the same as &buffer[cursor]. The cast is just so you're dealing with unsigned values to avoid weird signed behavior.

Comment: ok that makes sense. i guess. wish i knew why it was the same, but i'll settle for knowing that

Answer (score 4):

assuming these are stored MSB (i.e. big endian).

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)buffer + cursor;
uint32_t uiSize = (unsigned int)*p <<24 |
                  (unsigned int)*(p+1) << 16 |
                  (unsigned int)*(p+2) << 8 |
                  (unsigned int)*(p+3);
```

Cast the result to a signed int *after* assembly. Hideous I know, but so are my typing skills.

Note:I honestly can't remember if the implicit up-cast extends the sign from a char to an int or not but if it does, and any of the single bytes being or'd together here are top-bit-lit, you may be in for a surprise if *p was not. Thus the seemingly paranoid unsigned cast-o-festival, and the followup to cast to signed-int only *after* full assembled.

Comment: i like this and neonneo's because it allows me to not have to copy to a new buffer.

Comment: Thanks so much Craig, i liked the formatting and readability of @nneonneo's better but thanks for the effort man, i gave it an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
objSize = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++ i)
    objeSize += ((int)tmpbuffer[i]) << (8 * i);
```

OR

```
objSize = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++ i)
    objeSize += ((int)tmpbuffer[i]) << (8 * (3 - i));
```

for big endian as nneonneo pointed out

Comment: Why are you using `pow` for this? That will produce float values...use a shift instead!

Comment: *Note*: this solution is *little endian*; for big endian you would need `8 * (3-i)`.

Answer (score -1):

What you have should work fine but replace this

```
int32_t objSize = tmpbuffer;
```

for this

```
int32_t objSize = *((int32_t*)tmpbuffer);
```

- It must be stored and read in the same architecture.

Comment: It is simple serialization, if it gets stored the same way it is read, on the same platform, endianness is not an issue.

Comment: @NicolasArroyo -- The OP didn't say that.

Comment: This answer violates strict aliasing, resulting in UB. On some platforms this code can result in an illegal memory access due to an incorrectly aligned pointer. On other platforms where this appears to work it can perform poorly.

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `ntohl` function to convert from network to host byte-order.  No need to reinvent the wheel.  This also has the advantage of being somewhat portable and will work on big-endian and little-endian OSes as long as the correct headers are used.  Below is a Windows example, but the function is available on Linux as well:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "MARK\x00\x00\x00\x08";
    // Point to the 4-byte network (big-endian) order value.
    unsigned long * size = (unsigned long *)(buffer + 4);
    // Dereference and convert it.
    std::cout << ntohl(*size) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior.